# 4 million rows of data in a table

Tags: sql

I have 4 million rows of data in a table and I run this query

```
Select * from B
```

When I check the cpu usage, this query gets high cpu usage. My question is how can I improve cpu usage in this SQL query?

Comment: - Doctor, it hurts when I do this! - Don't do it then.

Comment: use `limit 100` or `top 100` something similar

Comment: Which SQL (Microsoft, Oracle, mySQL)     Also, what is in table B?   Does it contain a large number of columns?   What are you doing with 4 million rows?

Comment: And what are you going to do with those 4 million rows?

Comment: Why using `Select * from table` ? I always use where clause in my queries plus I have indexes on commonly used columns of where clause. I never get any problem and just for information my table contain around 120M records with 200 columns. and I also prune my data time to time.

Comment: yes it have a lot of columns

Comment: Plain and simple: only select **as many rows** as you **really need** (add a `WHERE` clause or a `TOP (n)` restriction), and don't just select all columns - only use those columns that you **really need** - to reduce the amount of data being returned

Comment: I wonder, how much CPU usage would look like, if you tried to output those results to the end user on the browser. Are you sure that you need to use `*` in your query? Plus there is no `WHERE` clause that could also narrow down your request query and thus reduce CPU usage.

Answer (score 3):

Are you likely to *read* a report with four million rows in it? *I* certainly wouldn't.

And, if not, why are you *generating* it?

If you're dumping the entire table for something like backup purposes, there are probably better ways, specific to the DBMS you're using.

If you *don't* need all the data (or even all of it at once), anything that can be used to limit what's coming out (such as a `where` clause to limit rows and/or more selective column selection than `select *`) should help you out, as will proper indexing so the conditions in the `where` clause can be sped up. This is *especially* true if the data is going "across the wire", you don't want to be sending unneeded gigabytes across the network.

If you *really* want all columns from all four million rows in normal output format at one time, you'll just have to suffer the performance hit. Databases offer all sorts of ways to efficiently get at data but, if you want the lot, there's not much they can do.

Having said that, there are way to mitigate the impact but it depends on how you have things set up. Some examples are:

- Have your database replicated, using the primary copy for its intended purpose and a slave replica for reporting. Then hitting the replica won't affect the primary one.
- If you can execute a number of smaller queries rather than one big one to get the same result, that's a possibility. For example one query to get all records from 2015, another after some rest time to get the 2014 ones and so on.

That's two things off the top of my head, no doubt there are others but, without knowing more detail, it's hard to advise specifics.

Comment: @Ahmad, which "that" are you referring to? I've updated the answer with quite a bit of extra info.

Comment: i need all of the data but i say how can i performancing cpu in sql?

Comment: @Ahmad, the two bullet points should be a good start if you genuinely need all the data.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simply reduce what your generating.

Limit the selections

```
SELECT TOP (100) * FROM B
```

Include a where clause

```
SELECT * FROM B WHERE COLA = XXX AND COLB = YYY
```

Specify the columns

```
SELECT COLA, COLB, COLC, COLD FROM B WHERE COLA = XXX AND COLB = YYY
```

OR, if you must return all 4 million rows.

Create a view that populates a temp table and set up a job with it in which is ran during "down time", middle of the night etc, then select from the temp table